# Discord.js won't play a sound in Voice Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a bot for a friend that will play a sound while he is streaming. For this to work I would have the bot play the sound when someone in the stream chat types `!scream` or any other noise.

But the farthest I have gotten is to get the bot to join the channel and *appear* to be speaking (the green light around the bot avatar will light up), but it will not stop or play any sound. I have installed all of the necessary dependencies such as FFMPEG and node-opus

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.content == '!leave') {
    console.log("Left")
    client.leaveVoiceChannel();
  }
  console.log(msg.id)
      if (msg.content === "!join") {
        msg.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            connection.playFile('J:/Discord-Bot/test.mp3');
            console.log("played")
      });


  if (msg.content === '!ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
}});

client.login('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Are you using [`node-opus`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-opus) (recommended)/[`opusscript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opusscript)? You'll also need [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) installed on the host machine.

Comment: Yes that is all installed and i get no errors. but just the fact that it wont play and sound

Comment: Where is `test.mp3` located?

Comment: I edited the post to show the full path

Comment: Are you using the full path in the code? The `file` parameter must be an *absolute* path.

Comment: Full path is what i saw everyone else using.